# How to join two fields in JSON array with jq

Tags: jq, xargs

I'm trying to get output in one line for 2 fields in the array using 'jq'

```
curl -X 'GET' "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/ethereum/market_chart?vs_currency=USD&days=10&interval=daily" -H 'accept: application/json'|jq '.prices[][]
```

gives me output like this:

```
1652227200000
2344.797715643986
1652313600000
2080.910243657776
1652400000000
1966.6991711336661
1652486400000
2010.214051125259
1652572800000
2064.229357512243
1652659200000
2147.047447880575
1652745600000
2025.8886983912162
1652832000000
2095.178884796724
1652918400000
1915.1771232664505
1653004800000
2023.8482593608173
1653070323000
1931.3963167096579
```

and I would like output to have date price (in one line) with space or tab in between like

```
1653004800000    2023.8482593608173
1653070323000    1931.3963167096579
```

I've tried with `'.price[][]|join(" ")'` but it didn't work.
possibly also format price to have 2 decimal places.  I was able to do it if I output only price like:

```
...|jq .price[][1]| xargs printf "%'.2f\n"
```

not sure how to do it if I have 2 values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second `[]` will bring you down to the elements you want to align. Omit it (but keep the first, as you want to access the elements of the `.prices` array), and format that array. You can, for instance, have the items tab-separated by using `@tsv`. Alternatively, you can use the `join` function with a separator string.

```sh
curl … | jq -r '.prices[] | @tsv'
```

```json
1652227200000   2344.797715643986
1652313600000   2080.910243657776
1652400000000   1966.6991711336661
1652486400000   2010.214051125259
1652572800000   2064.229357512243
1652659200000   2147.047447880575
1652745600000   2025.8886983912162
1652832000000   2095.178884796724
1652918400000   1915.1771232664505
1653004800000   2023.8482593608173
1653073654000   1942.3670724677067
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/EcJZTa67Noh)

```sh
curl … | jq -r '.prices[] | join(" | ")'
```

```json
1652227200000 | 2344.797715643986
1652313600000 | 2080.910243657776
1652400000000 | 1966.6991711336661
1652486400000 | 2010.214051125259
1652572800000 | 2064.229357512243
1652659200000 | 2147.047447880575
1652745600000 | 2025.8886983912162
1652832000000 | 2095.178884796724
1652918400000 | 1915.1771232664505
1653004800000 | 2023.8482593608173
1653073654000 | 1942.3670724677067
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7jW16LRuPC6)

---

To format the milliseconds column, convert it to seconds (divide by 1000), then use `strftime` (or `strflocaltime` for local time) with a format string. To round the price column to two decimals, multiply it by 100, use `round` and divide again.

```sh
curl … | jq -r '.prices[]
  | .[0] |= (./1000 | strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
  | .[1] |= (. * 100 | round / 100)
  | @tsv
'
```

```json
11-05-2022  2344.8
12-05-2022  2080.91
13-05-2022  1966.7
14-05-2022  2010.21
15-05-2022  2064.23
16-05-2022  2147.05
17-05-2022  2025.89
18-05-2022  2095.18
19-05-2022  1915.18
20-05-2022  2023.85
20-05-2022  1942.37
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/lkE3h1qXBY0)

Comment: Thanks @pmf ... perfect that works ... so easy .. once you know it.  Do you know if it's possible to format date to be human readable like `date  +%d-%m-%Y @1653073654000` , although this timestamp is in 1/1000s so has to be divided by 1000 to get proper date?

Comment: @DenisZ Added formatting to the answer.